# iPad PDF book with clickable objects

Tags: ipad, pdf, element, interactive

I want to display a PDF document as a book in an application on the iPad. It has to have the "page flip" animation. I also need to have clickable areas in the PDF document. When a given area in the PDF is clicked a dialog should appear in the application.

I have been searching around this site but I have mostly come across answers suggesting HTML or saying that the iPad has a built-in PDF reader but that won't do it in my case.

I heard about the [Leaves project](https://github.com/brow/leaves) and I have tried it out. It is easy to work with and gives the page flip animation I was looking for but as mentioned on the project's page, Leaves does not support interactive elements on a page.

Does anyone know of a way (preferably, a library) I can read a PDF, show it like a book and have clickable elements? It would be nice if I could just make the elements clickable inside the PDF and have the iPad application read these links.

The PDF will be created using Adobe InDesign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My NDA with Apple forbids me to tell too much but after having watched some of the videos from WWDC 2011, I will close this question.